# Insert spaces after certain characters in string c++

Tags: c++, insert

I am trying to format a string a certain way so that I can tokenize it later on. If the iterator is pointing to the first character of the string and it is an operator, we only insert a space after it. If it's pointing to the last character and it is an operator, only insert a space before it. Otherwise, insert a space before and after the operator. Once it gets to 'N', it successfully inserts the space before and after it but once I increment the pointer it shows this really weird value and then breaks:

```
Name     Value
i        "þîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþV^º"
input    "( 2 & 2 | 2 G 2 & 2 N 2|2L2&2=2)"
```

Here's my code:

```
input = "(2&2|2G2&2N2|2L2&2=2)";
// this is how (2&&2||2>=2&&2!=2||2<=2&&2==2) would be stored into the string
string::iterator i = input.begin();
while(i != input.end())
{
    if(isOperator(*i) && i == input.begin())
    {
        input.insert(i+1, ' ');
        i+=2;
    }
    else if(isOperator(*i) && i == input.end()-1)
    {
        input.insert(i, ' ');
        i+=2;
    }
    else if(isOperator(*i))
    {
        input.insert(i, ' ');
        input.insert(i+2, ' ');
        i+=3;
    }
    else
    {
        i++;
    }
}
```

Please help! :(

Comment: Looks like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: @POW: which is fine... if people didn't ask what was wrong with their solutions, and just asked us to provide our own solutions, the spectrum of solutions and hands-on "why not do X?" insights would be reduced.

Answer (score 0):

You have *undefined behaviour*. Your string iterator (as per the C++ standard) is being invalidated due to the `insert` calls which will modify the string contents and, probably, the memory location of the internal string buffer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your iterator is invalidated by your insertions in the string.  What do you think happens if the string resizes - moving the data content elsewhere in memory - and you keep trying to access the old buffer? (Hint: under the covers, the iterator is probably a `char*`).

If you change your code to use indices (i.e. `std::string::size_type`) and `operator[]`, then it will follow the string wherever it's allocated.

> Thanks for your answer! Could you please elaborate a little bit on that? I'm new to programming and unfamiliar with alot of things.

OK.  For a string, an iterator works like a pointer - remembering the memory address where a specific character in the string is stored.  So, after you set the iterator to begin, you have something like this...

```
[std::string object  x-]---------------->[text buffer  ]
                                          ^
                                          |
[iterator            y-]------------------+
```

...where "x" and "y" are private/hidden pointers holding the address, and the ---> and ---^ arrows show where the pointer points to... initially the buffer where the text is stored.

With `std::string`, as you insert new text into the `string` it fills up however much buffer it's currently got, and then automatically grabs a larger piece of memory at another address, copies the data over, releases the original buffer, then records the address of the new buffer in `x`.  If that happens, the `string` object does not update the iterator ("`y`"), so the situation's something like this:

```
                                      --->[bigger text buffer   ]
                                     /
[std::string object  x-]------------+     [!released memory!]
                                          ^
                                          |
[iterator            y-]------------------+
```

At this stage, if you dereference your iterator to attempt to see what character it addresses, you have undefined behaviour.  If you compare the iterator to the `string`'s `end()`, it may *never* match, causing you to loop until you crash.  If any other part of the program asks for memory (including another thread), it may be given the released memory and write new content over the text you had there before.  Basically, all hell breaks loose.

Contrasting with that, whenever you say e.g. `my_string[10]` it looks at the current buffer for `my_string`, incorporating any buffer movement that may have been caused by earlier `insert`s.  For that reason, it's much safer to move along the string using numbers [0..`my_string.size()`), as in:

```
for (std::string::size_type i = 0; i < my_string.size(); ++i)
    ...do things with my_string[i]...
```

Hope that helps clarify things for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you please elaborate a little bit on that? I'm new to programming and unfamiliar with alot of things.

Comment: Some explanation added.  If you want some general background on pointers, click on my profile - one of my top 3 or 4 answers is a gentle introduction/explanation for pointers.